# Ruby refresh object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I am a new to Ruby on Rails and I have a question on refreshing/reloading a relationship.  In the following code snippet, I am trying to set the 'store' property on a 'customer' object, then have the customer object returned with the nested store property, not its id. Is there a way I can set the store property, then tell RoR "get me the customer and hydrate the store" without doing another eager read load ?

```
store_id = params[:id];
store = Store.find( store_id );
session[ :store_id ] = store_id;

customer_id = session[ :customer_id ];
customer = Customer.find( customer_id );
customer.store = store;
customer.save

respond_to do |format|
  format.any(:json) { render :json => customer.to_json  }
end
```

Any help or any suggestions whether or not they pertain to the original question is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: So you're saying `customer.store` returns only the store ID?  It should be returning a `Store` class object.  Or are you asking how to eliminate the extra database call that using `customer.store` entails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to_json with params will do the trick for you:

In your example you need to change only last section (and the store object will not be loaded from db the second time)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.any(:json) { render :json => customer.to_json(:methods => :store)  }
end
```

Comment: Come over to chat !!! I have something interesting for you !!   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails-enterprise-application-developers

Comment: @Alony Thanks Alony, that got it to work.  Oh, are you Home Alony ?  I'm sorry, I just had too.

Comment: :)) nice that i could help you, and Alony is my name ;)

Answer (score 1):

On rails 3.1 you can access the association object directly via

```
customer.association(:store)
```

In earlier version of rails the association object wasn't exposed directly like this. You can then do stuff like

```
customer.association(:store).loaded?
customer.association(:store).target = store
```

This won't check that the customer and the store are associated (i.e. you can stick any old store in there) so be careful.

I'm not sure why you need this though -

```
customer.store = store
```

shouldn't cause the store object to be reloaded or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Frederick.  I had to tell json to serialize out my child object by using Alony's suggestion.